# How to get href values from a class - Python - Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
<a class="link__f5415c25" href="/profiles/people/1515754-andrea-jung" title="Andrea Jung">
```

I have above HTML element and tried using

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('link__f5415c25')
```

and

```
driver.get_attribute('href')
```

but it doesn't work at all. I expected to extract values in href.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: document.getElementById(id).href
You can also get an element by class name, but I only know this.

Comment: BTW, what is document and id? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first locate the element, then retrieve the attribute `href`, like so:

```
href = driver.find_element_by_class_name('link__f5415c25').get_attribute('href')
```

if there are multiple links associated with that class name, you can try something like:

```
eList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('link__f5415c25')
hrefList = []
for e in eList:
    hrefList.append(e.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefList:
    print(href)
```

Comment: Cool! This actually works very well. Besides, how can I extract all herf links under this class? should I write a loop or something?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer, do they all have the same class name?

Comment: YES! They have the same class. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, happy programming!